# custom logging in a packaged chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've given the docs a good looking over as well as SO, however can't seem to find any answers.

I have a packaged chrome app (new style, not legacy)
I can find many documents on enabling logging as in errors/crash reports, but can't find anything about custom logging. For example:

On initial load some 3rd party data is loaded via a api call, lets just assume it:

```
$http.get('/api/get-my-data').onSuccess(function(data){
  // Yay, I gotz the dataz. Do something
}).onFail(function(error) {
  // Damn son, something went wrong.
});
```

In the above pseudo code I'd like add to a chrome error/custom log to record the `onFail` condition. I'm not looking to record error in the sense that the app has crashed or a fatal error, I'm looking to log events that in the context of the app running correctly I regard as errors.

If an error caused the app to crash etc then I'd get a entry in the chrome logs, but there must (I assume) be away to log data directly to a log on the server that isn't considered an error (perfectly common if this was a web app on a server (log4j, KLogger, Morgan)) but I can't find it

Anyone else created a chrome packaged add and used the inbuilt logging?

Thanks

N.B. Just to be clear, we are talking about logging in a packaged app with javascript to a log file, not `console.log`

Comment: [chrome_debug.log](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)?

Comment: @wOxxOm I believe this is automatically written to by the chrome app, rather then allowing you to add entries. Might be wrong, but can't see any examples/docs as to how you'd write to this debug log. Also gets wiped on restart

Comment: I don't want to catch an app crash, if it crashes it will be picked up in the chrome logs automatically. I want to record logging information for certain events. Something like log4J but in the chrome app

Comment: Well, Chrome doesn't have a built-in customizable logging API. Which means you'll have to implement it yourself (maybe you can find some js wrappers that facilitate the task a little).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd answer this incase someone else comes across it as it's not clear form the google docs.

when you use `console.log` it gets sent to your strdout/chrome log file.

You have to enable logging in your chrome app launch config/flags, then any `console.log` in your code will show up where ever you set your `user-dir` to be.

It's not clear from the documentation, but basically your chrome app will automatically log and `console.log` you have

This includes other `console` methods.

Comment: Can you please share a link to the exact flag that one should edit for this?